# repeat loop upto certain number of times in r

Tags: r, repeat

I have a function which I want to repeat until a condition is met. But if it is repeated for over 100 times and the condition is still not met, I want to stop the repeat loop. How can I do this? The example code is:

```
repeat{
 m<- rexp(1)+2
 if(m<10){break}
}
```

Edited code 2:

```
counter<- 0
while(counter<=100){
  counter<- counter+1
   m<- rexp(1)+2
  if (m<10){break}
}
```

Comment: Add a counter inside the loop which increments every iteration, stop when counter bigger than x.

Comment: `counter <- counter + 1; if (counter>10) stop("reached counter limits)"`

Comment: @RLave is it like my edited code (please see the edited question)

Comment: `while` is precisely what you want.

Comment: @StephenHenderson is it like my second edited code?

Comment: The 1st edited code is wrong because it will loop exactly one time. `if(condition is TRUE) break else stop`.

Comment: The edit 2 is much better. In the first version of the code you have `m < 10` and in the other two versions you have `m > 10`. Which is it?

Comment: @RuiBarradas it was a mistake.it is m<10.

Answer (score 2):

you can have a `break` in a `for` loop as well:

```
for(i in 1:100) {
   # some computations
   if (whateveconditionyoulike) break
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
counter <-0   
ok <-1
while (ok=1 AND counter <=100)
{
 if (condition)
          ok <- 0
 counter <-counter+1
}
```

Replace the if(condition) with your actual condition fron the problem

Answer (score -1):

```
i <- 0
repeat {if (i==101 | (rexp(1)+2>2.8)) break;print(i);i<-i+1}
```

2.8 is just a random condition to meet. You can use any other condition you want.

Comment: 1) What is this `2.8`? Where does it come from? 2) Couldn't you have written one instruction per text line?

Comment: Added instruction as per your suggestion :-)

Comment: Not my downvote, but to me this seems different from what OP was looking for. You have a double condition `(i==101 | (rexp(1)+2>2.8)`

Comment: You should almost always use `||` rather than `|` in the test in an `if()` statement.  It only does as much evaluation as necessary to find the answer, whereas `|` will always evaluate both expressions.